# Solenoid Train - Best approach for magnetically guiding an object along a path?

Tags: solenoid, magnetics, induction, electromagnet, train

My project is to pull an object along a path with solenoids, by cycling their on/off state.  I don't know if ferrous core solenoids pulling steel would be more efficient than pulling a neodymium magnet with air-core solenoids.  Simple diagram is shown below.

Would ferrous core solenoids with a steel slug be more efficient than air-core solenoids with a neodymium slug?

My goal is to have smaller solenoids ~1cm in diameter.  I'm not sure how the size of the solenoid might affect this answer.  If voltge/current/power affects the answer, please let me know.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: If you have wheels, it’s easier but the Japanese maglev train floats on the repulsive force between the copper or aluminum coils in the track and a series of helium-cooled, niobium-titanium superconducting magnets. You must define your expected power levels required and then torque .